# MultiBinding across multiple DataTemplates with same ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have two data templates that make use of a multi-binding to control the visibility of a button, e.g. in data template A

```
<Button.Visibility>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HideFirstOrderedItemConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
         <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}" Path="Items"/>
         <Binding Path="Entity"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.Visibility>
```

and in data template B

```
<Button.Visibility>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HideFirstOrderedItemConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
         <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}" Path="Items"/>
         <Binding Path="Entity"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.Visibility>
```

The data templates are bound to the same list box items source and a data template selector is used to determine which datatemplate to use based on a property of the item in the list (Note: the datatemplate forms part of the ItemTemplate for the ListBox).

**Question:** Will wpf trigger the MultiBinding converter `HideFirstOrderedItemConverter` if either the binding to `Items` or `Entity` changes, or do both `Items` and `Entity` have to change?

Currently my binding on data template A doesn't fire when the `Items` property changes (an ObservableCollection that has items added and removed) and `Entity` does not change. Ultimately I would like the binding to fire on both data templates whenever the `Items` property changes.

If I comment out the binding to `Entity` in both templates as follows

```
<Button.Visibility>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HideFirstOrderedItemConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
         <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}" Path="Items"/>
         <!-- <Binding Path="Entity"/> -->
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.Visibility>
```

My converter gets hit when I add an item to the collection, but only for the data template asscoiated with the item just added. I'd like it to get hit for all items.

**UPDATE:**

The comments below from @ASh and @GazTheDestroyer helped my understanding here. I need to notify my view of a collection changed event using a property changed event (collection changed events are NOT surfaced to the binding framework). So by updating my XAML to

```
<Button.Visibility>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource HideFirstOrderedItemConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
         <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}" Path="DataContext.Entities"/>
         <Binding Path="Entity"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.Visibility>
```

where `DataContext.Entities` is the undelying ObservableCollection, and in the bound view model hook into the collection changed event of that ObservableCollection, i.e.,

```
Entities.CollectionChanged += CollectionChanged
```

where the `CollectionChanged` callback raises the notify property changed event on the `Entities` ObservableCollection. I believe this is the way to do it (might be nice to abstract this behaviour into its own type).

Comment: ObservableCollection that has items added and removed != Items property changes.  Property doesn't change, the reference stays the same. MultiBinding updates when *any* of included Binding changes - but none of them changes here

Comment: I'm slightly confused as the docs say "Represents a dynamic data collection that provides notifications when items get added, removed" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Do I need to bind to something else other that `Items` in the `ItemCollection`?

Comment: Add/Removes are notified by INotifyCollectionChanged. Your binding is just watching for instance changes via INotifyPropertyChanged, and your instance never changes. As a hacky fix you could add a third binding to Items.Count which should kick your converter when something is added/removed

Comment: Yes - I'm learning this quickly. I could add another property or perhaps in my view model hook into the CollectionChanged event and and raise the property changed on my underlying collection providing I update my xaml to point to `Path=DataContext.MyObservableCollection` instead of `Path=Items`. Not sure which is better.

Answer (score 0):

> Will wpf trigger the `MultiBinding` converter `HideFirstOrderedItemConverter` if either the binding to `Items` or `Entity` changes, or do both `Items` and `Entity` have to change?

Either. The problem is that the `Items` property of the `ListBox` isn't set when you add or remove items from the source collection. Bind to `Items.Count` instead:

```
<Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}"
         Path="Items.Count "/>
```

This property will change when you add or remove items from the source collection.

Also note that your `Entity` property must raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the converter to be re-invoked when you set it.

Comment: But won't that provide an `int` to my converter rather than the list of source items that my converter requires? I could add it as an additional binding just so it fires, but doesn't fee right to have a value injected into my converter that I'm not going to use.

Comment: Yes, it would provide an `int`. And yes, if you need a reference to the collection in the converter you should add another binding to the `<MultiBinding>`. If it doesn't "feel right", a converter is not what you want.